# how to Use payumoney gateaway on submit event in joomla chronoform v5

Tags: joomla3.0, payumoney, chronoforms

I have created a form which is rental agreement form using chronoform v5. It needs user to pay the processing fee on submit. I want to use payumoney gateway for that. I have installed payumoney kit, and created the payment method and done the configuration. My query is how to use this payumoney plugin/component on submit event?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answers I have already given you in the ChronoForms forums [here](https://www.chronoengine.com/forums/posts/f26/t100771/custom-payment-gateway-integration.html)